# How to delete all elements after a selected element?

Tags: html, jquery-selectors

This is my problem: I have to select and remove ALL the elements that follow one precise element.

Here an example of how my webpage is structured:

```
<h2>
<span class="myClass" id="Note">Note</span>
</h2>
<ol class="secondClass">...</ol>
<h2>...</h2>
<ul>...</ul>
<h2>...</h2>
<ul>...</ul>
<table class="tableOne">...</table>
<div class="otherClass">
```

In particular i have to delete ALL elements after  `<span class="myClass" id="Note">Note</span>`

I read a lot of topic about the `NextAll()` Jquery Selector, but however I can't manage to solve my problem.

Comment: There are no elements after that span in that DOM node (`h2`). That might just be your problem. However since you failed to provide your code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.nextAll() targets siblings and your span doesn't have any.  Perhaps you should be targeting its parent.  Eg,

```
$(".myClass").parent().nextAll().remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `nextAll` only gets sibling elements.  For a generic solution to this problem, if you use `nextAll` you would need to call it on the element and all parent elements:

```
$(".myClass").parents().andSelf().nextAll().remove();
```